# Open map to show direction from current location from application in Nativescript

Tags: angular, google-maps, location, nativescript

I have only coordinates for one marker.

I want to open google maps when I have Link to Directions.

So, I have this code in html:

```
<Button (tap)="raggiungi()">RAGGIUNGI</Button >
```

In ts I have this function:

```
   raggiungi() {
        let lat = 53.9187068;
        let lng = 27.5862874;
        let url = 'https://maps.google.com/' + '?' + 'daddr' + '=' + lat +','+ lng
        console.log(url)
    }
```

In console show this url: `https://maps.google.com/?daddr=53.9187068,27.5862874`

Now, when I have this link, how to open maps app with this coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [openUrl](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils#openurl-function) method

```
utilsModule.openUrl(YourUrl)
```